# Scale ImageButton inside chat bubble

Tags: android

I have a chat bubble set as `android:background` and an image set as `android:src`, I would like to fit my image such that if the image is bigger than my chat bubble `250dp height and/or width` (in the below example it is my height) then the TOP and BOTTOM should be cropped out so that the entire image remains within the chat bubble.

I DO NOT want to use the following:

- scaleType = cropInside | this centers my image leaving too much space on the width from left and right.
- scaleType = fitXY | this leaves the image evenly padded in the chat bubble height and width but the problem is that it stretches the image.

My XML:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_yellow"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

To summarize, I would like the same image chat bubble as whatsapp - what it does is that it keeps the ratio of an image (if portrait) by cropping off the top and bottom (or hiding rather) and only shows the entire image once it is expanded by single clicking on it.

Please see my image description below:

[image]

EDIT:

Below actual image (yellow background chat bubble done with 9 patch).

[image]

Comment: are you using 9-path image as background ?

Comment: please attach real image example so we could try to make it work

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the width (in dp) of the left part of your background image and add it as left padding. Background wont be affected by the padding

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_yellow"
        android:paddingLet="40dp"
        android:paddingStart="40dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Since the size of the `ImageButton` is given in dp, setting a left padding in dp would make it look same in all devices